# How to use Qt Creator as a smart editor?

Tags: cmake, qt-creator

I am looking to use Qt Creator 4.7 as a smart editor that helps navigate/refactor code and catch errors early.  I do *not* want to set it up to *build* the project—I only want to *edit* it.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

---

More specifically, I need to communicate the following information to Qt Creator *and not deal with anything build-related:*

1. Which are my source files, and what is their language (C, C++98, C++11, etc.)
2. The location of other includes files (like the `-I` compiler option)
3. Any special `#define`s to be assumed by the preprocessor

---

What I tried:

- I can create a generic project using File -> New File Or Project -> Import Existing Project. This allows me to specify 2. and 3. above, but not 1. Specifically, it 4.7.0 considers all files to be C++98 and won't let me use a newer standard.  The code model configuration no longer accepts the `-std=c++11` option. My impression is that the generic project support got little attention recently, and is no longer recommended.
- I attempted to set up a qmake project, but this seems to require a full Qt installation. I wish to avoid this, as I do not use Qt.
- I looked at how to use a cmake-based project, but this seems to require setting up a specific build target. Is this really necessary, or is there a way to use a cmake-based project to communicate only the required information to Qt Creator, and *not* set up a build? Assume editing a header-only library, without also including any `.cpp` files.  Again, it seems that a cmake-based project is not a good option, as the very purpose of cmake is to automate building, while all I need is to communicate essential information to my IDE.

---

Motivation: I often work on a library which is used to interface with [Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-mathematica). It has its own Mathematica-based build system.  Some required `.cpp` sources are auto-generated by Mathematica. Thus I can't fully switch to something like cmake, and doing so would give me no benefit (but it would take a considerable amount of learning time). I simply want to be able to use Qt Creator as a smart editor.

Note: In the past, it was possible to add `-std=c++` to the code model configuration and work around this issue. The latest version of Creator rejects this option.

Comment: The latest versions on Qt Creator use clang code model as default, so any settings to the build-in code model will have no effect. If clang is not working for you, disable it in `help > About plugins` and see if that helps.

Comment: @Jaa-c I think you misunderstood. The question is not about the clang code model, and the problem in this version is also not due to the switch to this code model. I have been using the clang code model for many Creator releases now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Qbs](http://doc.qt.io/qbs/) projects are a reasonably easy to use alternative to generic projects, and help solve this issue.

Advantages of Qbs over qmake/cmake:

- It comes with Qt Creator. There is no need to install anything else (such as all of Qt)
- It is designed to work well with Creator (unlike cmake which is a build system, not an IDE project format)
- It is not necessary to add explicit build information to a Qbs project. It is sufficient to specify which files are part of the project.

---

Getting started:

1. Run `qbs-create-project` in the project directory to create a barebones qbs file
2. Add the following at the top of the file, below `type`, and adjust as necessary:

   ```
   Depends { name: "cpp" }

   cpp.cxxLanguageVersion: "c++11"

   cpp.includePaths: base.concat([
       "/your/include/path1",
       "/your/include/path2",
   ])
   cpp.defines: base.concat([
       "NDEBUG",
       "SOME_SYMBOL",
       "SYMBOL_WITH_VALUE=123",
   ])
   ```

Instead of the files added by `qbs-creator-project`, you may want to use

```
files: [ "**/*.cpp" ]
```

to add all files, similar to how a generic project might look like.

Thanks to Nikolai Kosjar for helping set all this up!